# Trying to access API response from server on client-side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to get some data from Twitter to manipulate on the client-side. I'm using [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) to access the data.

I have a node server which I'll call **server.js**, and then a React front-end which I'll call **index.js**.

If I run the following code on **server.js** it logs the returned data (tweets) in the console:

```
T
  .get('statuses/user_timeline', { skip_status: true })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('caught error', err.stack)
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    // `result` is an Object with keys "data" and "resp"
    console.log(result.data)
  })
```

(where `T` is `const T = new Twit({ ... })`)

So I know this works.

---

What I'm trying to do is have **index.js** call the data from the server like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/internal-api/twitter/')
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
}
```

I then setup the code in **server.js** as follows:

```
app.get('/internal-api/twitter/', (req, res) => {
  T
    .get('statuses/user_timeline', { skip_status: true })
    .then(function(result) {
      // `result` is an Object with keys "data" and "resp"
      console.log(result.data)
      res.send(result.data)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('caught error', err.stack)
      res.send({ error: err })
    })
})
```

However, when I run **index.js** nothing logs on the server side and in the browser console the following is logged for `result.data`

```
Response {
  body: (...)
  bodyUsed: false
  headers: Headers {}
  ok: true
  redirected: false
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
  type: "basic"
  url: "http://localhost:3000/internal-api/twitter/"
  __proto__ : Response
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm more than happy to provide more code, I just didn't want to clutter up the question.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Update**: Below is `server.js` in its entirety.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

var Twit = require('twit')

const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: 'XXXXXXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXXXXXXX',
  access_token: 'XXXXXXXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXXXXXXX'
})

app.get('/internal-api/twitter/', (req, res) => {
  T
    .get('statuses/user_timeline', { skip_status: true })
    .then(function(result) {
      // `result` is an Object with keys "data" and "resp"
      console.log(result.data)
      res.send(result.data)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('caught error', err.stack)
      res.send({ error: err })
    })
})

// Priority serve any static files.
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build')));

// Answer API requests.
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('{"message":"Hello from the custom server!"}');
});

// All remaining requests return the React app, so it can handle routing.
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Could you provide your app.js code (where you configure the server).

Comment: I posted the rest of the server.js code. My App.js is in a `react-ui` folder and just deals with all the front-end stuff. High possibility I'm missing something you're saying here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `.then((response) => response.json())` on client side to read the stream to it completion:

> The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/internal-api/twitter/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use own *serializer*, because `express` can do this automatically for you, if you call `res.send()` with data:

```
app.get('/internal-api/twitter/', (req, res) => {
  T
    .get('statuses/user_timeline', { skip_status: true })
    .then(function(result) {
      // `result` is an Object with keys "data" and "resp"
      console.log(result.data)
      res.send(result.data)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('caught error', err.stack)
      res.send({ error: err })
    })
})
```

Comment: I removed the `serialized` function and updated the code to put the catch error at the end but I get the same response on the client side. I've updated my code above to reflect the current state.

Comment: Updated the answer, the problems was in missing `response.json()` call.

Comment: This certainly changes the response. Though I get a `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error. And when I log `response` and `response.json()` I get respectively: `Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/internal-api/twitter/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}` and `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}` I'm wondering if the server is not waiting for the API response before sending the data. The JSON seems fine.

Comment: Btw, what port do you listen? According your code it can be 5000: `process.env.PORT || 5000`, but the client sends the requests to `'http://localhost:3000/internal-api/twitter/'`. Do you define `port` in environment variables?

Comment: Ah, that could be it — the server runs on :5000 and the front-end on :3000. I'll investigate this later and see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help. Note to others: Two things were wrong, one was missing the `response.json()` as outlined in the accepted answer here and the other was the URL should have been :5000 where the server is, not :3000.